# One of 2 accounts in visual studio not identified as an azure account?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm having an odd issue with my Azure account. I have two accounts linked to my Visual Studio, the main one which contains all my resources, and a dummy one which I created to check the issue. When I try to publish, I can switch between the two accounts, and the dummy one works just fine. However, the main one keeps telling me I need to sign in with an Azure account.

I'm puzzled as to why this is happening. Can anyone provide any insight or suggestions for resolving the issue?

I've already tried signing out of Visual Studio and signing back in with my main Azure account, but the problem persists. If anyone has any solutions, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I have faced the same issue but could able to resolve and started to work fine as expected after a couple of sign ins and then restarting the instance.

[image]

Also, after choosing the right account while publishing the resource to cloud make sure you are publishing the resource into the main account's publish profile only.

[image]